Wicket Datepicker Timezone 'ui-datepicker-today' and 'ui-datepicker-current-day'
In my application, we are using Wicket and for Date picker I want to apply the following css class ‘ui-datepicker-today’, to a 'td' tag that already has a css class ‘ui-datepicker-current-day’ i.e. current date should have both of these css classes.
I think that somewhere wicket is internally applying these classes, just returning the updated innerHTML and thus dynamically creating the date picker (shown in below screenshot)
below screenshot shows the effect of css class ‘ui-datepicker-today’ on 6
and the effect of css class ‘ui-datepicker-current-day’ on 7


I think you use Wicket-jQuery-UI. Its source code is at https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/wicketstuff-jquery-ui-parent/wicketstuff-jquery-ui-calendar. The CSS classes should be set by jQuery UI itself.

I cloned (https://github.com/wicketstuff/wiquery) and found the class but still haven't found the fix!
